# What are the requirements for killing enemies with traps?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

In level 11 of *Mark of the Ninja* one of the challenges is to kill 5 enemies with traps. I killed more than 5 using environmental traps, but I saw no progress indicator nor did I get the challenge complete or even a challenge failed notice. Is it glitched or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this one with no trouble, and I saw a status update for each one.

For the most part, I knocked the bombs down using darts, and then attracted a guard/stalker's attention with another dart to get them to walk over it.  I believe these were the "Indirect Kill" type when they were scored.

According to some feedback left in the comments, this particular challenge only counts when you're in the "bandit" section of the level.  There are some challenges that are specific to sections of a level, and typically you'll get a "New Optional Challenge" alert when you're in the right place for this.

Comment: I did that for a _lot_ of guards. I'll replay it again and try again.

Comment: I did a replay of the level and it only tripped when I got to the bandit section.

Comment: @CyberSkull, ah, interesting.  There are some challenges that only count in certain areas - I wasn't paying that close of attention.  I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: This challenge seems pretty buggy: first time I played this level, I finished with 0/5.  But at the end of my second run, while I performed pretty much the exact same kills, I got the 5/5 without any trouble...  Weird.